# Optocoupler and op-amp: pull down without fast lane

Tags: operational-amplifier, switch-mode-power-supply

From Figure 5.25, does anyone know, how to get equation 5.112?

My understanding is the I<sub>LED</sub> should be equal to (V<sub>z</sub> - V<sub>op</sub>) / R<sub>LED</sub>.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If possible, put a link to the source so that we can have a look and see if it's explained or if there's an extra info/clue about your question somewhere else in the source document.

Comment: @RohatKılıç Not "if possible", [it's a must](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/referencing), to avoid plagiarism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The configuration shows a type 2 compensator in which the fast lane has been disabled. This is an excerpt from the [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1608075575) I published on loop control in 2012. The fast lane issue comes from the fact that, in a classical type 2 configuration, the LED current is ac-modulated by both \$V_{out}\$ and the active element output, whatever it is, a TL431 or an op-amp. This is what is shown in the below picture excerpted from a [seminar](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/The%20TL431%20in%20Switching%20Power%20Supplies.pdf) I built in 2009:

[image]

This two-lane architecture - the slow-lane via \$R_1\$ and the fast track through \$R_{LED}\$ - creates a minimum gain issue which can significantly hamper the compensation strategy. To reduce the LED current ac-modulation to a single contributor, one solution is to resort to a simple regulator whose role is to ac-isolate the LED current from \$V_{out}\$: if you modulate the output, then the modulated LED current will only come come from the TL431 cathode as in the right-side of the figure case. This is because we consider the dynamic resistance \$r_d\$ of the Zener diode to be extremely small, implying a good bias current (detrimental to consumption of course). When this front-end regulator is active, the LED current is solely dependent upon the cathode voltage (or the op-amp output) and the fast lane is gone.